# Is it possible to open a file within a batch file as another user?

Tags: postgresql, windows-command-prompt, batch

im trying to run psql.exe (postgreSQL) with an active code page set to 1252. I want to have a batch file that opens up a command prompt with that code page, then navigates to the psql directory to run it as "postgres" user. What I have is below:

start "test" cmd /k "chcp 1252 & cd c:\program files\postgresql\14\bin\psql.exe -U postgres"

how would I go about this? thanks!

Comment: you are looking for `runas`

Comment: I have tried using the runas command however my password is not getting recognised. When settings up postgreSQL a username and password was set up. I believe for the runas command to work I need to specify a domain name, how would I do that?

`start cmd /k "chcp 1253 && cd c:\program files\postgresql\14\bin && runas /noprofile /user:postgres psql.exe"
`